# ACF image not showing in Tailwind

Tags: php, tailwind-css, advanced-custom-fields

Tailwindcss has 2 ways of showing background images:

1. `<div style="background-image: URL();"></div>`
2. `<div class="bg-[url('/img/myimage.jpg')]">`

This Tailwindcss shows the background image perfectly:

`bg-[url('/wp-content/themes/sarasota-soccer-club/images/my-image.jpg')]`

but if I try to show an image with an ACF field, it won't work and I have no idea why:

`bg-[url(<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>)]` I like this way better because is more elegant. Using `style=""` in the HTML tag is ugly

but if I use it this way it'll work fine:

`style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>);"`

So, has anyone found an issue like this with `bg-[url(<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>)]`?

Comment: Do you get errors client side? `bg-[url('` is not the same as `bg-[url(<?php`, missing quotes.

Comment: No, it only shows an empty space with no image, that's all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Background w/ tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71947347/dynamic-background-w-tailwind)